# Need help in open layers javascript to create map with mapserver

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

Till now I've used the following code, but its map is not coming

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("ITASCA", "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe", {map: 'C:/world_mapfile.map'});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

I am unable to understand what is the meaning of mapserver and how it will work. I followed some instructions to add mapserver, but I'm unable to do it.

Can anyone help to understand how mapserver works and how to show map images?  The code that will show map I think is `OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer`, but I am not able to understand its flow.

I also created map file and now I am using this like `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=map&map=D:\world_mapfile.map`

But I am unable to create tiles using mapserver so map is not displaying. So I just want to know where I am doing something wrong in my code and how to add layer using mapserver.

Comment: The attached code is irrelevant because, it seems, you're asking "What is Mapserver"? It's also not clear if your code used to work up until some point.

Comment: Actually I don't know in depth regarding Openlayers so I just paste the whole code. Please check question again I've edited it.

Comment: If this is the code you're running it's evident that you're not passing the URL anywhere; according to the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/MapServer-js.html) URL should be passed as the second parameter (you're passing `"MapImageService"`). Check the source of the [official example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/mapserver.html) to see it in use.

Comment: Yes I have also tried that see my updated question but I am unable to set map file or may be something went wrong but code is still not working. Actually I am unable to understand that the image path and url that I set in map file is not getting useful that is why image is not showing but I tried everything but unable to get it work.

Comment: @Kryger, Do you think this http://www.mpbhuabhilekh.nic.in/bhunakshaweb functionality is possible via openlayers?

Answer (score 0):

Mapserver is a cgi extension for the Apache Webserver. Take a look at mapserver.org. This mapserver works with special configuration files with the file extension 'map'. The mapserver can connect to differnt sources of geo data and produce from that images (WMS) or for instance XML-Data (WFS).

If you want use mapserver on client site then at first you need to install a webserver and extend it with a mapserver installation. After that you need to configure one or more geo data sources (Postgis, shape files, ...).

For the beginning with OpenLayers is much easier to use slippy maps like OpenStreetmap for the background of your map. The dynamic content is imo much easier to produce with GeoJSON.

A working Mapserver layer example for OpenLayers can you find here:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/mapserver.html

Comment: I've installed ms4w that is the complete kit for mapserver and its example works and I am following the same. I have created map file but its not including in my project. Your instructions are correct but I am unable to do it. I have visited the website but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can you provide me some example code that I can use to be sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @user2935236 is this mapserver layer your base layer?

Comment: @user2935236 if you check your example with firebug ... sends your browser the request to your mapserver?

Comment: Yes its a base layer, I also debug from firebug it won't show mapserver file is called or not I think there is some mistake in my imagepath and imageurl in map server file but I am unable to find it.

Comment: @user2935236 If you don't see the request to mapserver in Firebug, then OpenLayers don't send anything. This behavior has nothing to do with the mapserver installation. Somethin in your client code don't work right. Take a look at the example in my edited answer.

Comment: Ok when I put this code to file then it also works. So now what I exactly want that I want to show the map with image I have with mapserver so its possible or not like in mapserver layer we need to give url but as I am working on localhost and I have image so how to show my image in map using mapserver. Its possible or not and if yes then how?